# How to join table in LINQ and return list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this webservice method to get a list of records based on the prefixSA that I pass in from my controller.

But I don't want to display a guid. In another table BizV the name for each guid are stored. As the image below.
[image]

How do I change the code so that from the listing it will get the shortdesc and pass back **`tolist();`**

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<ca_ConfigiDeal> Get_iDealConfig(String caller, Guid? prefixSA, Guid? codeCalendar, bool? iscash, bool? isfreeMM, bool? isonContract, Guid? product, Guid? requestType, out ReturnStatus returnStatus, out String errorMessage)
    {
        List<ca_ConfigiDeal> list = null;
        DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Now;
        String _spName = "Get_iDealConfig";
        Object _parameters = new { caller, prefixSA, codeCalendar, iscash, isfreeMM, isonContract,product, requestType};

        returnStatus = ReturnStatus.Unspecified;
        _customMessage = String.Empty;
        ERGODataContext _context = null;

        try
        {
            _context = get_DBContext2();
            DataLoadOptions dataLoad = new DataLoadOptions();
            dataLoad.LoadWith<ca_ConfigiDeal>(x => x.ref_PrefixSA);
            dataLoad.LoadWith<ca_ConfigiDeal>(x => x.ref_CodeCalendar);
            dataLoad.LoadWith<ca_ConfigiDeal>(x => x.ref_Product);
            dataLoad.LoadWith<ca_ConfigiDeal>(x => x.ref_RequestType);

            var _list = _context.ca_ConfigiDeals.Where(x => x.isDeleted == false);
            if (prefixSA.HasValue)
                _list = _list.Where(x => x.PrefixSA == prefixSA);
            list = _list.ToList();
            if (codeCalendar.HasValue)
                _list = _list.Where(x => x.CodeCalendar == codeCalendar);
            list = _list.ToList();
            if (iscash != null)
                _list = _list.Where(x => x.isCashnCarry == iscash);
            list = _list.ToList();
            if (isfreeMM != null)
                _list = _list.Where(x => x.isFreeMM == isfreeMM);
            list = _list.ToList();
            if (isonContract != null)
                _list = _list.Where(x => x.isOnContract == isonContract);
            list = _list.ToList();
            if (product.HasValue)
                _list = _list.Where(x => x.Product == product);
            list = _list.ToList();
            if (requestType.HasValue)
                _list = _list.Where(x => x.RequestType == requestType);
            list = _list.ToList();


            if (list.Count == 0)
            {
                returnStatus = ReturnStatus.NoRecord;
            }
            else
                returnStatus = ReturnStatus.Success;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            handleExcept(ref returnStatus, caller, ex, _spName, _parameters, _startTime);
            _customMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            errorMessage = String.Format("{0}: {1}.{2}", (Int32)returnStatus, returnStatus.ToString(),
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(_customMessage) ? String.Empty : String.Format(" {0}.", _customMessage));
            traceEnd(_context, caller, _spName, _parameters, _startTime, returnStatus, errorMessage);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

ca_idealconfig table 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your model for those **Guid datatype** must change to **string** because you are getting its string? and you forgot to loadoptions

```
_context.LoadOptions = dataLoad;
```

Answer (score 1):

a is pointing to ca_ConfigiDeals, b=> BizV table

```
        var join = _context.ca_ConfigiDeals.Join(_context.BizV, a=>a.guid, b=>b.rguid, 
    (a,b)=>new{
          PrefixSA = a. PrefixSA,
          guid = a.guid, 
          calendercode = a.calendercode,
          product = a.product,
          request = a.request,
          ShortDesc = b.ShortDesc
          }).Where(x => x.PrefixSA == prefixSA);
```

after join u can play with like a normal model

Edit:: I'm misunderstanding

This answer is not be a best practice but it will work

```
var new_list = new List<Object>()
    foreach(var item in _list){
       var temp = new {
            PrefixSA = _context.BizV.Find(item.PrefixSA).ShortDesc;
            CodeCalendar = _context.BizV.Find(item.CodeCalendar).ShortDesc;
            Product = _context.BizV.Find(item.Product).ShortDesc;
            RequestType = _context.BizV.Find(item.RequestType).ShortDesc;
        }
        new_list.Add(temp);
    }
```

Edit Aagin ::

```
    [WebMethod]
        public List<object> Get_iDealConfig(String caller, Guid? prefixSA,out ReturnStatus returnStatus, out String errorMessage)
        {
            var list = new List<object>();
            DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Now;
            String _spName = "Get_iDealConfig";
            Object _parameters = new { caller, prefixSA };

            returnStatus = ReturnStatus.Unspecified;
            _customMessage = String.Empty;
            ERGODataContext _context = null;

         try
            {
                _context = get_DBContext2();
                var _list = _context.ca_ConfigiDeals.Where(x => x.isDeleted == false);
                if (prefixSA.HasValue)
                     _list = _list.Where(x => x.PrefixSA == prefixSA);
                foreach(var item in _list){
                   var temp = new {
                        PrefixSA = _context.BizV.Find(item.PrefixSA).ShortDes,
                        CodeCalendar = _context.BizV.Find(item.CodeCalendar).ShortDesc,
                        Product = _context.BizV.Find(item.Product).ShortDesc,
                        RequestType = _context.BizV.Find(item.RequestType).ShortDesc
                    };
                list.Add(temp);
                };


                 if (list.Count == 0)
                    {
                        returnStatus = ReturnStatus.NoRecord;
                    }
                    else
                        returnStatus = ReturnStatus.Success;

                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                handleExcept(ref returnStatus, caller, ex, _spName, _parameters, _startTime);
                _customMessage = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                 errorMessage = String.Format("{0}: {1}.{2}", (Int32)returnStatus, returnStatus.ToString(),
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(_customMessage) ? String.Empty : String.Format(" {0}.", _customMessage));
                 traceEnd(_context, caller, _spName, _parameters, _startTime, returnStatus, errorMessage);
            }

        return list;
```

Comment: erm @kichnipan there is 4 column from the database i need to get their shortdesc. i have same feeling of ur code should work just that im not sure about what u mean by a=>a.guid can u be more specific?

prefixsa , calendercode, product and request type.

Comment: Sure you can I don't know your table but I think table ca_configiDeals have PrefixSa, guid and in the table BizV you have rguid, ridno, BizClass, ShortDesc. We declare ca_configiDeals to 'a' and BizV to 'b' in join operation we need a key so that key clearly is guid. table ca_configiDeals have guid and table BizV have rguid and we'll select column by new { column = table.column } if you want prefixsa from ca-ConfigiDeals and shortdesc from BizV it gonna ba new { prefixsa = a. predixsa, shortdesc = b.shortdesc }

Comment: i uploaded my ca_idealconfigs table please help me check again haha freshy to linq because the 4 column in configideals their data all match rguid from bizV rguid. @kichnipan

Comment: I upload the image haha i need it to compatible with the whole function.
actually i think there is smthing wrong at a=>a.guid i don have guid column in configideals table @kichnipan its all shown in the image

Comment: Bro can we not use list<object> ?? if you change my list<ca_ConfigiDeal>list=null iwill have alot of errors haha @kichnipan

omg damn this so hard for me, my brain not functioning LOL

Comment: I guess error in view right? oh i juse see method type is list<ca_ConfigiDeal>. you have to create a new model that contain ShortDesc and other

Comment: nope its just here haha its linq DataSource thingy lol thats y im having hard time  @kichnipan

Comment: What about change method type to List<object> ?

Comment: i think i try ur code its list<object> but not working hahah